# intellij Scala Project issue

Tags: scala, intellij-idea

I try to import an Scala Project into intellij. Intellij founds starts to load the dependencies then I got this error

How can I solve this issue?

```
[error] Expected non-whitespace character
[error] --addPluginSbtFile=C:\Users\Firstname Lastname\AppData\Local\Temp\idea1.sbt
[error]                                      ^
```

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is fixed in the Scala plugin for IntelliJ IDEA update 2019.3.18 and release 2020.1

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/SCL-15360

Answer (score 1):

The path should not contain BlankSpaces.

**You have a blank space between Firstname LastName:**

C:\Users\Firstname Lastname\AppData\Local\Temp\idea1.sbt

**Possible solution:**

C:\Users\FirstnameLastname\AppData\Local\Temp\idea1.sbt

Comment: Its the System Path from Windows wich comes up with the microsoft User Account. So Its not possible. Any hints to set the path into `""` don't know from where this comes.

Comment: ok that seems to be an known issue in current intellij version

Comment: Try to add `%20` to the PATH: `C:\Users\Firstname%20Lastname\AppData\Local\Temp\idea1.sbt`

Comment: issue tracker link for reference: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/SCL-15360